# jQuery touch events iOS won't work

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, touch

I'm having trouble with jQuery touch events in iOS.

Here is what I've done:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var iX = 0,iY = 0,fX = 0,fY = 0;

        document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {

            var touch = e.touches[0];
            iX = touch.pageX;
            iY = touch.pageY;

        }, false);

        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {

            var touch = e.touches[0];
            fX = touch.pageX;
            fY = touch.pageY;

        }, false);

        document.addEventListener('touchcancel', function() {

            var dX = fX - iX;
            var dY = fY - iY;

            var tg = dY/dX;
            if(tg < 0) tg = -tg;

            if(tg <= 0.5 && fX > iX) rightSwipe()
            else if(tg <= 0.5 && fX < iX) leftSwipe()

        }, false);

        function rightSwipe(){
            $("#body").removeClass("bg2");
            $("#body").addClass("bg");
        }

        function leftSwipe(){
            $("#body").removeClass("bg");
            $("#body").addClass("bg2");
        }
});
```

When you touch your finger into the screen, it saves the finger position.
When you move your finger and release it, it saves the last finger position.
By simple geometry, it discovers the direction you swiped.

This script works very well on Android 4.1.2 using Google Chrome and Android default browser.
When I try it on iOS using Safari, it doesn't work.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen the `touchcancel` event on Mobile Safari on the iPad. Have you tried using `touchend` instead? Perhaps this:

```
function upHandler(event) {

    var dX = fX - iX;
    var dY = fY - iY;

    var tg = dY / dX;
    if (tg < 0) tg = -tg;

    if (tg <= 0.5 && fX > iX) rightSwipe()
    else if (tg <= 0.5 && fX < iX) leftSwipe()
}

document.addEventListener('touchcancel', upHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('touchend', upHandler, false);
```

If you use jQuery, you can replace this:

```
document.addEventListener('touchcancel', upHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('touchend', upHandler, false);
```

With:

```
$(document).on('touchcancel, touchend', upHandler);
```

Comment: Nop. I tested and both touchstart and touchmove works. But neither touchcancel and touchend works.

Comment: I missed you weren't using jQuery. I'll update my answer. When using jQuery, it'll do nice things like this for you with `on` and such.

Comment: Thanks! It works!
Could you do an example using event listener + jquery?

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano Sure -- I've added an example of how to use jQuery's `on`.

Comment: But by doing that, how do I get the "event" variable that contains the touch position?

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano I wondered how you were doing that. I've updated my answer -- the event will be the first parameter to the callback function so you can do this `function upHandler(event)` or you can access it via the `arguments` pseudo array (but a named parameter is very much preferred).